# How to implement reusable xib in other uiviewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, xib

I have a an app where I need a form (uitextfield + UIButton) that can be reused in several viewcontrollers.

What is the best way of doing this? I am thinking create a myForm~iPad.xib and myForm~iPhone.xib with one myFormVC.h and one myFormVC.m. But then how would I import this form into my Storyboard views or in to ViewControllers through code?

Or is there a better approach altogether?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches to take but it all depends on your business need so you would need to do some research. This is how you would load a xib via code though:

```
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNib" owner:self options:nil];
    MyNibViewController *myvc = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```